# Is there a way to skip precompilation when I push on heroku?

Tags: heroku

When I push my code on heroku, with git, bundler and precompile run each time, even if I didn't change anything on my assets. Is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a good article about this problem : http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/faster-deploys

tl, dr :

In `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'dalli'
gem 'memcachier'
```

---

On the command line:

```
heroku addons:add memcachier:dev
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile
```

---

In `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.assets.cache_store = :dalli_store
```